# Replace all trace of occurrences for space

Tags: php, regex

How to replace all occurrences of text, regardless of caps lock, by spaces?

Occurrence: "ksm" (with or without caps lock on letters) to "k sm"

Examples:

```
"BulkSMS" to "Bulk SMS"
"BULKSMS" to "BULK SMS"
"BulkSMSs" to "Bulk SMSs"
"bulksms´s" to "bulk sms´s"
"bulkSMS(dot)com" to "bulk SMS(dot)com"
"bulksms@domain.com" to "bulk sms@domain.com"
...
```

Comment: Have you tried something to solve this problem(research, pseudo code, code/attempts, ...)?

Comment: What System\OS are you using?

Comment: @alim-ansari Linux Ubuntu / Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `preg_replace` with  following `regex`

```
/((bulk)(sms))/i
```

**Explanation :** Capturing word `bulksms` with `i` modifier for `case-insensitive` strings

```
$str = "bulksms bulKsms bulKSMS BulkSMS BULKSMS bulkSMS(dot)com bulksms´s BulkSMSs";
echo preg_replace("/((bulk)(sms))/i","$2 $3",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if your question is not very specific, i guess you want to do that in php, so you can use preg_replace_callback:

```
$strinToParse = 'test: bulksms bulKsms bulKSMS BulkSMS BULKSMS bulkSMS(dot)com bulksms´s BulkSMSs';

$string = preg_replace_callback('/(ksm)/i', function ($matches) { return 'k sm';}, $strinToParse);
```

will return

> test: bulk sms bulk sms bulk smS Bulk smS BULk smS bulk smS(dot)com bulk sms´s Bulk smSs

Comment: did not match at all: preg_replace('/(.*k)(sm.*)/i', '$1 $2', "test: bulksms bulKsms bulKSMS BulkSMS BULKSMS bulkSMS(dot)com bulksms´s BulkSMSs") return: "test: bulksms bulKsms bulKSMS BulkSMS BULKSMS bulkSMS(dot)com bulksms´s Bulk SMSs"

Comment: That why it's important to have a question well redacted. Nothing allow me to understand your input is one big string with sevral occurence of *kms*. Look at my edited answer, it should works.

Comment: #Alisson,

Good to know if you managed to solve the problem. You can post the solution here that may be helpful for someone looking for the same...

Comment: #Alim The right solution is voted the @Uchiha: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35810837/4892525